# Reason for orphaned inodes and boot failure fixable by manual fsck?

Tags: boot, shutdown, fsck, inode

my first post here.

I am running 18.04.1 and I have recently gotten an error while booting - the screen remains black after POST and nothing happens. I went into recovery mode and found that my root partition doesn't get mounted due to orphaned inodes and the like - I cannot supply a log since I have rebooted twice since fixing that and I do not actually know how to access historical boot logs. I could fix it by running `fsck.ext4 -p /dev/mapper/name-of-root-partition`, and everything is fine and dandy again... However, I know this will probably happen again in the future, as I have had the exact same problem with Debian - it was in fact one of the reasons I switched to Ubuntu (the other being worse compatibility on Debian and some other small problems I didn't feel like fixing by hand, on Ubuntu it just werks).

Now fixing the problem is easy and rather pain-free, but I wonder what could be the reason, as it happens fairly frequently (I reckon twice a week) - I realized it might have something to do with me shutting the computer down with `sudo shutdown now`. Am I on the right track? I could not find any proper information about this approach being "dangerous" but at the same time everybody seems to be inputting various arguments before `now`, never running it "raw".

My hardware is pretty generic and I would assume rather unimportant, really. I have a single Kingston SSD and the weirdest thing in my setup is probably me forcing the kernel to load `amdgpu` instead of the default `radeon` drivers.

Comment: `sudo shutdown now` would not leave you with orphaned inodes, let alone an unbootable system.

Comment: I knew one fellow who dutifully told the system to shutdown the right way, then (unwisely) immediately held the power button. You're not doing anything like that are you?

Comment: Oh, no, nothing of the like. I just went with `sudo shutdown now` and washed my hands of the all thing, letting it die, which usually happened immediately. Now, just in case, I use the dedicated "power button" in the tray, choosing "Shutdown" (without invoking it through shell). But apparently it is not necessary?